# Android - Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I have the default app which comes with Android studio which has a label on screen. When I try to run the app in an emulator, I get these errors:

[image]

I searched and then updated my sdk api to level 23. My gradle build is set to compile for 23 as well but I get this error and it won't run.

[image]

Comment: Change appcompat version to 25, e.g. `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

use `compileSdkVersion 25`

try this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your_id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
}
```

**EDIT**

For Sdk 23

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your_id"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
```

the idea is to use same version

Comment: I dont have api 25

Comment: Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: F:\Android\android-sdk\android-sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: did you have api 23 ? also you can download api 25

Comment: Yes, I have api 23

Comment: I can't download api 25, how do I find compile string for api 23?

Comment: Downloading build tools v23, can you explain me what is appcompat and support dependencies? and where do you find their exact version strings ?

Comment: BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Thank you

Comment: here : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html you can learn about different dependencies and their contexts..